# Sharepoint list item auto populate Active directory employee and their manager details

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I want to create one Sharepoint 2013 List,

Manager name : (If you select Manager 'A' employee name has to populate who are all reproting to A).

Employee name : List of employee who are all reporting to Manager A which is selected in frist column.

from Active directory

Please help me out, how to do this task

Comment: you can refer the link : http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/116185/how-can-i-create-people-directory-in-sharepoint-2013

Comment: Hi Hardik, Thank you for your guidance. my task is populating employee name and manager name in list item column from Active directory...

Comment: thats good. rate my answer if it resolved or helps you in anyways. thanks!